# htaccess config to serve jxl / avif if file exist

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, jpeg-xl

I want to configure the htaccess file on a wordpress installation / apache server to serve a JpegXL if the browser supports it and if not serve a .avif file. If both formats are not supported serve the original JPEG. The files are names `image_name.jpg` `image_name.avif` `image_name.jxl` and are accessible on the server.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# Serve JXL if the browser supports it and the file exists
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/jxl
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.jxl -f
RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpg|jpeg)$ $1.jxl [T=image/jxl,E=accept:true]

#Serve AVIF if the browser supports it and the file exists, and JXL wasn't served
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_accept} !=true
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/avif
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.avif -f
RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpg|jpeg)$ $1.avif [T=image/avif]
</IfModule>
```

Currently the condition `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.jxl -f` and `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.avif -f` evaluate to false and the file is not replaced. When deleting this line the correct file is displayed

Comment: Is your document root actually set to the base folder of WP - or is it perhaps some WP-in-a-subdirectory + rewrite-to-remove-folder-name kind of setup? What happens if you try and check against just `./$1.jxl` instead?

Comment: by changing it to `RewriteCond ./$1.jxl -f` it does change anything, by changing it to `RewriteCond ./$1.jxl` the server displays a blank page / error

Comment: And if you just check for `$1.jxl`, without prefixing it with any path?

Comment: Where is the .htaccess file located? Where are the images located? The behaviour you are seeing could happen if the .htaccess file is not in the document root.

Comment: @CBroe if you don’t include a file-path in that condition then it will certainly fail to find that file. Using `.` (to presumably represent the CWD) does not make sense in this context.

Comment: the htaccess file is located here: `/STRATO-apps/wordpress_01/app/.htaccess`
the files are located here: `/STRATO-apps/wordpress_01/app/wp-content/uploads`

Comment: And what is the document root directory? Do you have a `RewriteBase` directive? And if so, what is this set to?

Comment: @MrWhite I am not sure as I lack the knowledge. I suspect root dir. is `/STRATO-apps/wordpress_01/app/` This is also where htaccess is stored. Regarding rewriteBase: There is is line in htaccess `RewriteBase /`  The full file is here: https://pastebin.com/rBAFdF5L

Comment: I did some further investigation and could print out all server variables, "document root" is in a totally different place from what i assumed. 
https://pastebin.com/9nF8CPj7